# Postgres 9.5.3 JSON fields comparing dates with operators weird behavior on Mac OSX 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm having a problem on both of my Mac machines, but not on my Linux machines. Using date comparison operators like this does not work on my Mac:

```
# Ruby code
dt_start = DateTime.current - 10.days
dt_end = DateTime.current
id = 1
# last_seen field looks like this in db when we store it:
# {"1":"2016-11-21T22:17:47.269Z"}
User.where("(last_seen->'?')::text <> 'null'", id
).where( "(last_seen->'?')::text > ?", id, dt_start
).where( "(last_seen->'?')::text <= ?", id, dt_end)

SELECT "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE ((last_seen->'1')::text <> 'null') AND ((last_seen->'1')::text > '2016-11-12 18:13:03.432534') AND ((last_seen->'1')::text <= '2016-11-22 18:13:03.432534')
```

Returns no records on my Mac, but works on Linux

Upon breaking apart that query, when I use `>` operator, I get no records no matter what date range I put.

```
User.where( "(last_seen->'?')::text > ?", id, 10.years.ago).count
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "public"."users" WHERE ((last_seen->'1')::text > '2006-11-22 23:46:59.199255')
=> 0
```

When I use only the `<` operator, I get all records that have non-empty `last_seen` fields no matter what date I put.

```
User.where( "(last_seen->'?')::text < ?", id, 10.years.ago).count
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "public"."users" WHERE ((last_seen->'1')::text > '2006-11-22 23:46:59.199255')
=> 42
```

I've even tested by switching my time on my Mac to match my linux box timezone which is UTC. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
So DateTime and ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone formatted to ISO 8601 return different formats:

```
DateTime.current.iso8601 # => "2016-11-23T19:18:36+00:00"
Time.zone.now.iso8601    # => "2016-11-23T19:18:44Z"
```

Since the `last_seen` JSON field stored dates using ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, I tried changing the SQL queries to match that format, but same problem:

`last_seen: {"1"=>"2016-10-20T14:30:00Z"}`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "public"."users" WHERE ((last_seen->'1')::text <> 'null') AND ((last_seen->'1')::text > '2016-01-23T19:03:11Z') AND ((last_seen->'1')::text <= '2016-11-23T19:01:10Z')
=> 0
```

Then I changed `last_seen` JSON to have the second format with DateTime, and queried with DateTime instead with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You say that your JSON column contains things like:

```
{"1":"2016-11-21T22:17:47.269Z"}
```

The value in that object is a real ISO-8601 timestamp. The queries that ActiveRecord is producing:

```
SELECT "public"."users".*
FROM "public"."users"
WHERE ... ((last_seen->'1')::text > '2016-11-12 18:13:03.432534') ...
```

are using not-quite-ISO-8601 timestamps, not the missing `T` between the date and time components in `'2016-11-12 18:13:03.432534'`. The results of your `text` comparisons will depend on how `'T'` and `' '` compare and that's not guaranteed to be what you want it to be or even to be consistent across platforms.

If you're going to do this sort of thing you'll need to make sure the formats are consistent. I'd go with strict ISO-8601 since that is the One True Timestamp Format and it will behave consistently everywhere. The `#iso8601` method will take care the formatting for you:

```
User.where("(last_seen->'?')::text <> 'null'", id)
    .where( "(last_seen->'?')::text > ?", id, dt_start.iso8601)
    .where( "(last_seen->'?')::text <= ?", id, dt_end.iso8601)
```

Calling `#iso8601` yourself will give ActiveRecord a string so you'll bypass whatever timestamp-to-string formatting AR wants to use. There's also a `precision` argument to `iso8601` if you one second precision isn't good enough.

---

As an aside, are you sure that JSON is the right approach to this? A separate table might be a better fit.

Comment: updated answer, yeah I think I'm going to get rid of this when I can and make a separate table, or create a view or something